# Let $V$ be the set of all bounded solutions of the ODE:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was stuck on the following problem:

> Let $V$ be the set of all bounded solutions of the ODE:
>   $u''(t)-4u'(t)+3u(t)=0,\,\, t \in \Bbb R$. Then I have to prove that $V$ contains only the trivial function $u \equiv 0.$

We see the general solution is given by $u(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^{3t}$. Now,I am stuck and not sure which way to go. Little explanation in this regard is welcome. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Suppose $u$ is a solution and $c_2 \ne 0$. Prove that $u$ is unbounded. Therefore $u \notin V$. Repeat this argument with $c_1$. Which solutions are therefore left in $V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idea suggested by Hans Engler: if $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded function, then 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-3t}u(t)=0$$
Draw a conclusion about $c_2$... Also, if $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded function, then 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-t}u(t)=0$$
Draw a conclusion about $c_1$.